# I have a question about the feature data type of machine learning

Tags: python, scale, lda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BazND.png)

Hello
I'm experimenting with lda, which separates 0,1 targets through 3 features.I have the same data as the picture.

First of all, a standard scaler was used to scale each data,
It indicates an error such as "setting an array element with a sequence."

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

This is the code that I tried.
X_train is a numpy array in which the data frame of the above picture is divided through train_test_split.

To summarize the question,

1. Can I use those arrangements as features?
2. If it's okay to use it as it is, how should I scale it?

Comment: I think this question might get more responses on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also the image markup is invalid so it's appearing as a link